# Change flag to 0 and 1 On button click android

Tags: android, button

when i click first time on a button its background image is changed. then when i click another time on the button again it should get its firs background. I have set a flag globally and then on button click increment flag counter. but when i click first time nothing happens but on second time the button take the new image.

desired:

1st click: flag becomes 0: button take default background.
2nd tap: flag becomes 1: button take new background. and flag is reset to 0.

it should be 1st tap 0 to 2nd tap second tap 1 => 0 , 3rd tap=>0 reset.

Here is my code:

```
flag++;

switch (flag) {
    case 0:
        cbhead.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cbxbox);
        checkValue1 = TAGN;
        System.out.println("flag off : " + checkValue1);
        break;
    case 1:
        cbhead.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cbxboxchecked);
        checkValue1 = TAGN;
        System.out.println("flag on: " + checkValue1);
        flag = 0;
        break;
}
```

Comment: in your case 0 you dont put your flag to 1

Comment: What is your flag's default value?

Answer (score 2):

Just increment flag inside case 0:

```
flag=0;
switch (flag) {
    case 0:
        cbhead.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cbxbox);
        checkValue1 = TAGN;
        System.out.println("flag off : " + checkValue1);
    flag++;
        break;
    case 1:
        cbhead.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cbxboxchecked);
        checkValue1 = TAGN;
        System.out.println("flag on: " + checkValue1);
        flag = 0;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because you're incrementing the flag before the switch statement. so if it starts to 0, when you hit the button it is incremented before it enters the switch statement.